# Why isn't it printing "So Close"?

Tags: c

I and a few friends are new at learning C. We made a simple Guess The Number program and we came across a problem.

At the line it should've print "So Close!", may someone tell why isn't it working as expected?

Thank you for your time. (edited the code)

````
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<time.h>

int main ()
{
    int number, upper = 100, lower = 0, nGuesses = 1, Guess;
    srand(time(NULL));
    number = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1) + lower);

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &Guess);

  do
  {
    if(Guess!=number)
    {
    printf("Try again. You're at %d tries.\n", nGuesses);
    scanf("%d", &Guess);
    }
    if(Guess>number)
    {
      printf("Too high!\n");
    }
    else if (Guess<number)
    {
      printf("Too low!\n");
    }
    else if ((Guess + 5) >= number || (Guess + 5) <= number)
    {
      printf("So close!");
    }
    else if (Guess == number)
    {
      printf("Number is %d. You got it in %d guesses!\n",number, nGuesses);
    }
    nGuesses++;
  }while (Guess!=number);
  
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Because you have it as `else if` after testing for greater and lesser. That branch will never be taken because the *ONLY* way Guess could *not* be greater and *not* be lower, but be close, is if it were equal.

Comment: And once you fix that, `(Guess + 5) >= number || (Guess + 5) <= number` is always true.

Comment: try moving the guess+5 checks as the first if test.

Comment: I would recommend `(Guess - 5) <= number && number <= (Guess + 5)` since that more closely tracks how such a relationship would normally be expressed mathematically. @NateEldredge your suggestion maintains the original logic error.

Comment: Rather && to see if the number is in the 10 range

Answer (score -2):

Your control logic is not quite right.
See the following example using the Ada language:

```Ada
with Ada.Text_IO;         use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

procedure Main is
   subtype Num_Range is Integer range 0 .. 100;
   package rand_num is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random (Num_Range);
   use rand_num;
   Seed        : Generator;
   Num         : Num_Range;
   Guess       : Integer;
   Num_Guesses : Natural := 0;
begin
   Reset (Seed);
   Num := Random (Seed);
   loop
      Put ("Guess the number: ");
      Get (Guess);
      Num_Guesses := Num_Guesses + 1;
      if Guess = Num then
         Put_Line
           ("Number is" & Num'Image & ". You guessed it in" &
            Num_Guesses'Image & " guesses.");
         exit;
      elsif Guess < Num then
         Put ("Guess too low");
         if Guess >= Num - 5 then
            Put_Line (" but you are close.");
         else
            Put_Line (".");
         end if;
      else
         Put ("Guess too high");
         if Guess <= Num + 5 then
            Put_Line (" but you are close.");
         else
            Put_Line (".");
         end if;
      end if;
   end loop;
end Main;
```

When the guess is too low the program states that. If it is also within the near range the program states that. Similarly if the guess is too high the program states that. If the program is within the near range the program also states that.

The loop exits immediately after printing the message when the guess equals the number.

A sample run gives the following output:

```
Guess the number: 50
Guess too high.
Guess the number: 25
Guess too low.
Guess the number: 35
Guess too low but you are close.
Guess the number: 38
Guess too high but you are close.
Guess the number: 37
Number is 37. You guessed it in 5 guesses.
```